# Why is my CollectionView not returning image?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, swift3

I have been working with a Collection View controller and 2 Table View controllers. I want my 1st Table View controller to return an image into my Collection View when tapping the Save button (unwind segue). The 2nd Table View controller holds two icon images.

Now, at runtime, I can see the different cells being added (I set grey background to the cell) when tapping Save, but the image selected in 2nd TableView controller does not show up and I end up with grey squares instead.

Code in Master Collection View Controller:

```
var iconImg = [Icon]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}


override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of items
    return iconImg.count
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cellIdentifier = "glanceCell"
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! MasterCollectionViewCell

    // Configure the cell

    return cell
}

// MARK: - Navigation

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "ShowIconDetail" {
        let pickedIconTableViewController = segue.destination as! PickedIconTableViewController

        // Get the cell that generated this segue

        if let selectedCell = sender as? MasterCollectionViewCell {
            let indexPath = collectionView?.indexPath(for: selectedCell)!
            let selectedIconImage = iconImg[((indexPath)?.item)!]
            pickedIconTableViewController.iconImage = selectedIconImage

        }

    }

    else if segue.identifier == "AddIcon" {
        print("Adding new icon")

    }

}

@IBAction func saveToCollectionViewController(_ sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {

    if let sourceViewController = sender.source as? PickedIconTableViewController, let iconImage = sourceViewController.iconImage {

        // Add a new icon image.
        let newIndexPath = IndexPath(item: iconImg.count, section: 0)
        iconImg.append(iconImage)
        collectionView?.insertItems(at: [newIndexPath])

    }

}

@IBAction func cancelToCollectionViewController(_ segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {

}
```

If anyone can tell me what the fix should be to display that selected image, please do!

Comment: Sorry Matt... I found what was wrong! Will update.

Comment: You were right, Matt - no need to throw that much code in. Was too into it...

Answer (score 0):

I was so focused on the unwind segue that my cell in CellForItemAtIndexPath was not configured... I was missing the following: cell.iconImg.image = iconImg[indexPath.row].icon. Thanks if you bothered reading :).